# Asp Net Core e-mail validation

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Asp.Net Core 3.1

I am trying to validate e-mails when a user registers on my App.  So register, confirmation e-mail with link etc.

I have found this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

They suggest using SendGrid, but that is $90/month.  Does anyone know a free way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article suggests SendGrid because they offer a free account. The free account link is in the middle of the article.

https://sendgrid.com/free/

You can send 100 emails per day which is good for small applications.

Comment: If you click the link, it says the free version does not do e-mail validation?  OR am I missing something?

Comment: @RobL I'm not sure where you see that. I don't see anything about email validation on the free page.

Comment: Ahh.  The e-mail validation mentioned has nothing to do with e-mail confirmation.  Got it.  Thanks Rosco.